# error passing to another activity after a listview Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, arraylist, adapter

I have the issue...

```
02-20 02:57:09.854: E/AndroidRuntime(12431): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception"
```

...later...

```
02-20 02:57:09.864: E/AndroidRuntime(12431): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList
```

...in a ListView populated with SQLite, the listView works fine, but later when i try to use onListItemClick, to get the parameters of the item on the list view selected and show it in other layout, the program stops and the DDMS says this "Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception" later says "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList" in a ListView"  maybe i handled bad my adapter of the Arraylist?

This is my main class:

```
public class lay_main extends ListActivity 
    {
    public ListView list;
public DBHelper myAdap;
protected SQLiteDatabase db;
public Cursor cursor;
DBHelper Context;
DBHelper ArrayList;

//adapter cAdapter class
protected ListAdapter adapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lay_main);  

    collectXML();
    setupDataBase();
    setupAdapter();

}      
private void collectXML() 
{
     list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);  

}

public void setupDataBase() {
    myAdap = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
    myAdap.insertCourses();             
}

public void setupAdapter()
{
if(myAdap.getCourses()!=null)
    {
    cAdapter adapter = new  cAdapter(this, R.layout.list_courses, myAdap.getCourses());
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) 
 {
        super.onListItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CourseDetails.class);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) myAdap.getItem(position);
        intent.putExtra("COURSE_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
        startActivity(intent);  
 }
}
```

my class CourseDetails for receive and show the data:

```
public class CourseDetails<BDHelper> extends Activity {
protected TextView tTitle;
protected TextView tInstructor;
protected TextView tLength;
protected TextView tRating;
protected TextView tTopic;
protected TextView tSubject;
protected TextView tDescription;

protected  int courseId;    
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.course_details);

    courseId = getIntent().getIntExtra("COURSE_ID", 0);
    SQLiteDatabase db = (new DBHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT title, instructor, length, rating, topic, subject, description FROM courses",         
            new String[]{"" + courseId});


    if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
    {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            tTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tTitle);
            tTitle.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));

            tInstructor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tInstructor);
            tInstructor.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("instructor")));

            tLength = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tLength);
            tLength.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("length")));

            tRating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tRating);
            tRating.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("rating")));

            tTopic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tTopic);
            tTopic.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("topic")));

            tSubject = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tSubject);
            tSubject.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subject")));

            tDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tDescription);
            tDescription.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description")));

    }


}}
```

My Adapter class:

```
public class cAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
Context context;
ArrayList<Courses> courses;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public cAdapter(Context context, int layout_id, ArrayList<Courses> Courses) {

    super(context, layout_id, Courses);
    this.context=context;
    this.courses=Courses;


}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_courses, null);
    try{
        //components
        TextView txt_title=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        TextView txt_instructor=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txt_instructor);
        TextView txt_length=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txt_length);
        TextView txt_rating=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txt_rating);
        TextView txt_topic=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txt_topic);

        //asign values
        txt_title.setText(courses.get(position).title);
        txt_instructor.setText(courses.get(position).instructor);
        txt_length.setText(courses.get(position).length);
        txt_rating.setText(courses.get(position).rating);
        txt_topic.setText(courses.get(position).topic);

    }catch(Exception ex){}      
    return row;
}
}
```

not that I'm doing wrong, really would appreciate your help.

Comment: paste your getItem method code.

Comment: Hi jitendra, thanks for read, my class CourseDetails receive and show the data from the class lay_main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override getItem method of adapter and return Cources Object from getItem,

```
Override
public Courses getItem(int position)
{
   return courses.get(positon);
}
```

and in  SetupAdapter method:

```
public void setupAdapter()
{
if(myAdap.getCourses()!=null)
    {
    adapter = new  cAdapter(this, R.layout.list_courses, myAdap.getCourses());
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

and change on itemClick as follows:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) 
 {
        super.onListItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CourseDetails.class);
        Courses course= (Courses) adapter.getItem(position);
        intent.putExtra("COURSE_ID", course.title));
        startActivity(intent);  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jitendra, this send me the error: Cannot cast from ArrayList<Courses> to Courses, why?

Comment: have you been overrided getItem method

Comment: thank you very much, that it apparently resolved, however I spend another problem later in CourseDetails.class, with "Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception" now is: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to{start activityComponentInfo com.mariposatraining.courses / com.mariposatraining.courses.CourseDetails}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x2b6be8 "but I think I should open another question for solve that detail, apparently I'm doing wrong the statement in SQLite to perform the search with the cursor inside that class!